# Eclipse RCP & SWT Widgets & NLS

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, equinox

Does anyone know if its possible to do NLS to some SWT Widgets in SWT\RCP application?

**remark:**
With JFace components its possible if you create own equinox fragment to plugin **org.eclipse.jface**, (contains `messages.properties`), so let me say if I want to make Slovak NLS to `JFace` components I create `messages_sk.properties` in my fragment.

Does anyone knows if this could be done also to SWT which is part of plugin **org.eclipse.ui** ?

I am developing application which uses SWT `FileDialog`, which has default english buttons etc.
I want to make them other language without making my own dialog, but changing NLS..

Comment: Yes, but be careful here - I think that `FileDialog` will raise your system's file picker dialog and thus would be localized based on your operating system's language?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you have a chance to internationalize the text of the buttons of [org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/FileDialog.html).

SWT is using the system file dialog here. For me with a german win32 system the text is in german. This indicates that the button texts are also system dependent.

[image]

**PS:**
SWT is not part of the plugin `org.eclipse.ui`. FileDialog is part of the plugin `org.eclipse.swt.<ws>.<os>.<arch>_<version>.jar`

where:

- *ws* - window system: `gtk`, `win32`, etc.
- *os* - operating system: `win32`, `linux`, `solaris` etc.
- *arch* - architecture: `x86`, `x86_64`
- *version* - version id (something like `3.100.1.v4234e`)

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end? The correct keys to use in SWTMessages language file for a FileDialog?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the parts in `org.eclipse.swt` can be localized. I don't know about an option to localize `FileDialog` and similar "widgets", because the library calls directly some Win32 API (or similar API on other OSes) to create it. Therefore this part is highly OS dependent and wouldn't be portable if you change it somehow.

If you want to localize other parts of `org.eclipse.swt`, it's relatively simple. Just create a fragment (e.g. `org.eclipse.swt.nls`), where host would be `org.eclipse.swt`. Create a package `org.eclipse.swt.internal`.

Than copy a file `SWTMessages.properties` from `org.eclipse.swt.<ws>.<os>.<arch>_<version>.jar/org/eclipse/swt/internal` to the new package and rename it to `_SWTMessages.properties`.

Then you can create localized `SWTMessages_<lang>.properties` files (where `<lang>` is the language abbreviation: e.g. `sk`, `de`, `fr`).